# What causes the FileHelpers error: System.Data.DataTable is defined in an assembly that is not referenced?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, filehelpers

I am trying to use `FileHelpers CsvEngine.CsvToDataTable`.
As a result I get an error telling me the following:

> *The type 'System.Data.DataTable' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

I am developing for Windows CE device with .Net 3.5. As I understood `CsvEngine.CsvToDataTable` needs .net 2.0

So my question is:

1. Is there a `Filehelper` for .Net 3.5 or will I have to migrate all my projects to .Net 2.0?
2. What (refer to any lib you know) will be useful to dump CSV to datatable like `CsvToDatatable` is?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be able to reference a 2.0 dll in a 3.5 project. 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
2. You could try https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper